# How does Ada access Windows 8.1/10 APIs, and can 64 bit programs for Windows be generated?

Tags: ada

I am considering to learn Ada. I found several resources online, and *Programming in Ada 2012* by Barnes is on its way to here, so that should get me started.

The target machines for the future Ada programs are Intel 64 bit, and the target OSes are Win 8.1 and Win 10.

However, I was not able to find an example on how to interact with the Windows API in order to draw and manipulate Windows. Could someone please direct me to a source, so that I can have a look at how such code would look like?

Also, all I've read so far indicates, that Ada compiles only 32 bit executables for Windows. Is it correct that I can not generate true 64 bit Windows programs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [recent GNAT community release](https://www.adacore.com/download/) does target 64bit. An alternative is [TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/) which has provided a GNAT release targeting 64bit for a while.

There is [Win32Ada](https://github.com/AdaCore/win32ada) which is a binding to the Windows API. However, I don't think it has been updated with new APIs of Windows 8.1 or Windows 10. However, you can always import functions from the Windows API into Ada yourself.

There is [GtkAda](https://github.com/AdaCore/gtkada) which allows you to use GTK to create GUIs. However, these are not „native“ Windows GUIs.

Comment: Thanks for the links. Since I've also asked about how Windows calls look like, I will point to such using GWindows, in order to make this answer complete: http://www.gnavi.org/index.php?Command=Class&ClassID=GWindowsWin32&CID=411#_Toc11492894